# Galaxy S3 won't boot, gets stuck at the "Samsung Galaxy S3 GT" screen

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, rom-flashing, boot-loop, reboot, accessibility

I seem to have the same problem as many other Galaxy users with the **Boot Loop**. I cannot access my phone:

- I am not able to load the Stock ROM or factory reset it, nor erase any data.
- It is stuck at the ***Samsung Galaxy S3 GT*** screen and then **turns off**.
- If I go to "download" or "volume up mode" (I am sorry I don't know the name) it turns off.

I have already tried:

- pulling the battery out
- waiting until the battery has no juice
- connecting to PC to try to update the firmware

Does anybody know what should be done?

Answer (score 1):

It might be a power button issue. when you take the battery out, and put it back in does the phone automatically turn on by itself? or do you have to press the power button to do that? You should turn it back on with the power button, if it turns back on automatically then it means your power button has gotten stuck. What I did was hold it and kept pressing it a few times in order for it to get unstuck. it'll turn on like normal once it's unstuck